# Polar decomposition-uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix (with complex entries). Then it can be expressed as $A=UP$ where $P=\sqrt{A^*A}$ and $U$ unitary. If $A$ is invertible then $U$ is uniquely determined. If $A$ is real then $P=\sqrt{A^TA}$ and $U$ is orthogonal. I'm interested in the following question:

> Is it always possible for a *singular* matrix $A$ to produce *two different* unitary matrices $U_1,U_2$ such that $A=U_1P=U_2P$ where $P$ as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes: it is always possible.

$U$ will satisfy $A = UP$ if and only if it satisfies
$$
U(Px) = Ax \quad \forall x\in \Bbb C^n
$$
that is, it sufficient to determine how $U$ acts on the image of $P$, which in your case is a strict subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ be an orthonormal basis for the image of $P$.  Extend this to an orthonormal basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$.  Let $V$ be a unitary transformation that, with respect to this basis, has the form
$$
V = \pmatrix{I_{r \times r} &0\\0 & V'}
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and $V'$ is an arbitrary unitary matrix.  Then for any $U_1$ such that $A = U_1P$, $U_2 = VU_1$ will also be unitary and satisfy $A = U_2P$.  As long as $V \neq I$, we will have $U_1 \neq U_2$.

Comment: So the most "narrow" situation is the following: $A$ has $n-1$ dimensional range and one dimensional kernel, then $V'$ is just scalar. If we are interested in real matrices still you always have at least _two_ choices: $V'=1$ or $V'=-1$ (in this case instead of unitaries we have orthogonal matrices). If we add the assumption that for example $detU=1$ then we finally get that such $U$ unique and this is the best we can claim, right?

Comment: @truebaran interesting. I have a feeling that you're right: if $A$ has rank $n-1$ and we constrain $U$ to be real with determinant $1$, then there is a unique $U$. However, my answer to your question is insufficient (on its own) to confirm that this is the case.